# How to redefine a view in a state inheritance in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, view, routes, states

I need to have to states in order to show different views if the user is logged in or not. My problem is that in the app.dashboard state does not show the view, but if I put that view in the views part in the state app it works. I want to inherit because in different states I will need to show different pages.

This is that part of the code:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('welcome',{
        url:"/",
        controller: "HomeController as home",
        views: {
            'topbar-menu-view': {
                templateUrl: '/partials/topbar/loginForm.html'
            },
            'home-view': {
                templateUrl: '/partials/login.html'
            }
        },
        data: {
            requireLogin: false
        }
    })
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'topbar-menu-view': {
                templateUrl: '/partials/topbar/userOptions.html'
            }
        },
        data: {
            requireLogin: true
        }
    })
    .state('app.dashboard',{
        url:"/",
        controller: "HomeController as home",
        views: {
            'home-view': {
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

Am I doing something wrong? Because I looked for some examples and it seems to be like this.

The index file is something like this:

```
<body ng-controller="HomeController as home">
   <topbar home="home"></topbar>
   <div id="homeScreen">
       <div ui-view="home-view"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add your views referred to the error part.

Comment: I've just added the index file which includes the views.